# How to color the area under a scatter plot with different colors

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to this forum and thankful for all the help I can receive.

I tried searching for quite a bit on the shading the area under the graph with different colors but for some reason my code wont work with it. So I had to remove that piece of code.

I want to shade the area under my scatter plot with colors based on my data ( example: 0 to 2: red ; 2 to 5 : blue ; >5 : green ). I had found a code that applies a gradient in a vertical manner but I wanted the colors to appear horizontally across the graph.

The following is my javascript code:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
.range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left");

var area = d3.svg.area()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
.y0(height)
.y1(function(d) { return y(d.conc); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

function make_x_axis() {        
return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
     .orient("bottom")
     .ticks(20)

function make_y_axis() {        
return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(20)

// load data
d3.json("convertcsv.json", function(data) {
data.forEach(function(d) {
 d.conc = +d.conc;
d.time = +d.time;
  });

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.conc; })]);

svg.append("area-gradient")
  .attr("id", "temperature-gradient")
  .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
  .attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", y(50))
  .attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", y(60))
.selectAll("stop")
  .data([
    {offset: "0%", color: "steelblue"},
    {offset: "50%", color: "gray"},
    {offset: "100%", color: "red"}
  ])

svg.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "area")
  .attr("d", area)
.style("fill", function(d) {            
        if (d.conc >= 5 ) {return "#00CC00"}  
        else if (d.conc < 5 && d.conc >= 2 )   { return "#0000CC" }  
       else     { return "#00CC00"}     
    ;})                                     

svg.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {            // <== Add these
        if (d.conc >= 5 ) {return "#00CC00"}  // <== Add these
        else if (d.conc < 5 && d.conc >= 2 )   { return "#0000CC" }  
       else     { return "#CC0000"}     // <== Add these
    ;})                                     // <== Add these
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.time); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.conc); })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
        div.transition()        
            .duration(200)      
            .style("opacity", .9);      
        div .html(d.conc + "%")  
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
        })                  
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
        div.transition()        
            .duration(500)      
            .style("opacity", 0);   
    });

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
.attr("class", "tooltip")               
.style("opacity", 0);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Concentration");


svg.append("g")         
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(make_x_axis()
        .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat("")
    )

svg.append("g")         
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .call(make_y_axis()
        .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat("")
    )

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define gradients in several directions, and even define the colors of each stop with CSS. It's better to define gradients under the `defs` tag in the SVG element. The direction of the linear gradient is given by the attributes `x1`, `y1`, `x2` and `y2`. For instance, if you have `x1 = 0`, `y1 = 1`, `x2 = 1` and `y2 = 1`, the gradient will be diagonal, from the upper left to the bottom right corner. Consider the following code:

```
var div = d3.select('#svg-container'),
    svg = div.append('svg');

svg.attr('width', width).attr('height', height);

// Create the svg:defs element and the main gradient definition.
var svgDefs = svg.append('defs');

// Define the gradient from (0, 0) to (1, 0) (horizontal)
var mainGradient = svgDefs.append('linearGradient')
    .attr('id', 'mainGradient')
    .attr('x1', 0).attr('y1', 1)
    .attr('x2', 0).attr('y2', 0);

// Create the stops of the main gradient. Each stop will be assigned
// a class to style the stop using CSS.
mainGradient.append('stop')
    .attr('class', 'stop-left')
    .attr('offset', '0%');

mainGradient.append('stop')
    .attr('class', 'stop-right')
    .attr('offset', '100%');

// Use the gradient to set the shape fill, via CSS.
svg.append('rect')
    .classed('filled', true)
    .attr('x', padding)
    .attr('y', padding)
    .attr('width', (width / 2) - 1.5 * padding)
    .attr('height', height - 2 * padding);
```

Also, you don't need to set the stop colors in JavaScripts, you can configure them using CSS.

```
<style>
    .stop-left {
        stop-color: #3f51b5;  /* Indigo */
    }
    .stop-right {
        stop-color: #009688;  /* Teal */
    }
    .filled { fill: url(#mainGradient); }
</style>
```

The result:

[image]

The complete code of this example is available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/pnavarrc/20950640812489f13246). More details in the [SVG linearGradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/linearGradient) element in the MDN site. Regards,

Comment: Thank you for the code. However, it still did not work for me. I tried changing the code to match my need but the circles and the axis of the line chart disappeared, leaving only the area ( which did not have the gradient). Is there a way where I could specify the range from the data for the colors to appear ?

Comment: I tried changing the coordinates for x1,y1 and x2,y2 to change the direction horizontal but i am ending up only with vertical gradients. May I know what coordinates i must use in order to get a horizontal direction ?

Comment: I tried '(x1', 0)('y1', 1)('x2', 0)('y2', 0) but for some reason it fills my area with just one colour. My area is an area under an exponential curve. Do you think this could be the reason ?

Comment: There is a working example here http://bl.ocks.org/pnavarrc/20950640812489f13246, it will be easier to help if you post a working fiddle.

Comment: I was just about to post that I was able to get it horizontal. I just have to find a way to make the stops based on my array values. Thanks a bunch for the help :)